# How to use Bearer Authorization Token in Maven settings.xml

Tags: maven, authorization, settings

Currently application using username and password (encrypted) to download Maven artifacts through JFrog Artifactory.

How can we specify we want to connect using a HTTP Header`"Authorization: Bearer <identityToken>"` insead of the username and password in the settings.xml file?

I have tried using the xml tag token like below

`<token>${identityToken}</token>`

But that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in `~/.m2/settings.xml`.  The documentation for `maven-resolver-transport-http` is [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-resolver-transport.html).
You can create a JWT access token from your Artifactory user profile, or as an admin [here](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-platform-administration-documentation/access-tokens).

```
<server>
  <id>my-server</id>
  <configuration>
    <httpHeaders>
      <property>
        <name>Authorization</name>
        <value>Bearer ${env.JFROG_TOKEN}</value>
      </property>
    </httpHeaders>
  </configuration>
</server>
```